# Redirect does not seem to be reliable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect the user to the article they have clicked when they click the article. Sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it seems to do nothing.

```
const searchResult = props => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

    const listItemClicked = url => {
        setUrl(url);
    };

    if (url !== '') {
        console.log(url);
        return <Redirect to={url} />;
    }

    return (
        <li key={props.resultName} className="result-list" onClick={() => listItemClicked(props.url)}>
            <div className="result">
                <p>{props.resultName[0].toUpperCase() + props.resultName.slice(1)}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default searchResult;
```

The console.log(url); shows the url every single time though, just something to keep in mind, hence why I said the redirect does not seem to be very reliable/ also need to usecase of if I am already at `/help` and I redirect to `/help` will it cause any issues, I don't think so but just adding that in there too.

Any recommendationson on how I could tackle this differently or what I could do to make this more reliable? How would you do this if you was pushing this into production? Thanks in Advance!

*Update* - It seems to give me the error when I am on /help and I redirect to /help

Comment: I am not sure if this is the root cause of your issue, but [you should never put a `key` at the top level of a component](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys) - it needs to be used in the context of the loop where the component is being rendered. If you're doing `myArray.map(item => <SearchResult />)` somewhere, *that's* where the key needs to go: `myArray.map(item => <SearchResult key={item.resultName} />)`

Comment: @JoeClay  Never knew that Joe thanks, I will keep that in mind! Unfortunatly my issue seems to be that once I am redirected to /help and I press another article that redirects me to /help it goes crazy...

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `Redirect` instead of `Link`?

Comment: @codecubed.io No reason until I did a bit of research, I think I was looking at it wrong the whole time, Link is the way forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

return <Link to={url} />;
```